# Maven - increase memory for JVM

Tags: java, maven, memory

I have tried multiple ways to increase the given memory for the JVM.
The OS is: Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS
To start the program I use the *exec-maven-plugin*.
I start it with following command: `mvn clean compile exec:java`.

However I need more memory.
To check the given memory for the jvm I use: `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`. (Currently it's 32gb, 120gb are on the system)

To increase it I have tried multiple things.

1. Using the surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Xmx102400m</argLine>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()) still prints 32gb.

2. `set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx102400m"`
3. `mvn clean install -DargLine="-Xmx102400m"`
   (To be honest I don't even have an idea why this should work.)

I can't use intellij or eclipse to increase the jvm memory, since the program runs on a server.
I don't have any idea left and I can't find an other solution on the web.

Comment: I think your question is answered in great detail at https://stackoverflow.com/q/23701207/1523342.

Comment: You know this `-Xmx102400m` mean `102GB`, because each `1m` it is equal to `1 MB`. Do you have `102 GB` of memory in your computer?

Comment: Why don't you just build an executable jar and then run it with `java`?

Comment: Really using such an extreme old version of maven-surefire-plugin?

Answer (score 2):

This argument should do the trick: `-Drun.jvmArguments="-Xmx512m -xms1024"`

Comment: you mean to expand the compile command?   Like this:  ```mvn clean compile exec:java -Drun.jvmArguments=" "```?   
If so, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Maven 3.1 you can add jvm options to file `./.mvn/jvm.config`
For example:

```
-Xmx4G -Xms4G -Djava.awt.headless=true
--show-version
```

For all Maven versions you can do this

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4G -Xms4G"
```