# When Surivor Space Size Limit is Reached, What Exactly Happens?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In the Java Heap, when the survivor space size limit is reached, what references get promoted to the old generation? Every survivor? Or just the oldest of the survivors? Is this configurable?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695298/java-gc-why-two-survivor-regions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically there are two survivor spaces. Each time objects that survived are moved to the other space. JVM knows how many times object has been moved between survivor space and based on that you can tune GC

More info:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeil/index.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html